# Microsoft Teams uses 10% cpu until opened after reboot?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams

I have a company PC with Windows 10 and several applications including Microsoft Teams.

Recently I have noticed that after a reboot Task List reports Teams to consistently use 10% CPU (4 core i7) until I click on the icon to start it after which it settles at approximately 1.5%.   I only use Teams intermedient and I would like it to essentially not do this.  Uninstalling is not an option.  My uneducated guess is this is a busy loop for a resource.te

What should I look for?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the loading of Teams at startup using the startup tab in the Task Manager. It is confusingly called *Update.exe*, but you should recognise the icon.